# How to arrange list item in spinner in ascending order

Tags: java, android

How to arrange items in list descending instead of the image:

[image]

to be like this:

```
10
20
50
100
```

and this is the below adapter I use:

```
package com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class GenericArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

  // Vars
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;

  public GenericArrayAdapter(Context context, List<T> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    init(context);
  }

  // Headers
  public abstract void drawText(TextView textView, T object);
  public abstract void drawSubText(TextView textView, T object);

  private void init(Context context) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
      vh = new ViewHolder(convertView);
      convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
      vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    drawText(vh.textView, getItem(position));

    return convertView;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;

    private ViewHolder(View rootView) {
      textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
    }
  }

  static class ViewHolderSub {

    TextView textView;

    private ViewHolderSub(View rootView) {
      textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sub_text);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolderSub vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_item_child, parent, false);
      vh = new ViewHolderSub(convertView);
      convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
      vh = (ViewHolderSub) convertView.getTag();
    }

    drawSubText(vh.textView, getItem(position));

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

and this is the `setupPrice()` method which I need to arrange the entities in:

```
    private void setupPrice() {
        final GenericArrayAdapter priceAdapter = new GenericArrayAdapter<Sm>(getContext(), slectedSmsEntities) {
            @Override
            public void drawText(TextView textView, Sm object) {
                if (object != null && object.getPrice() != null) {
                    if (LngID == 0)
                        textView.setText(object.getPrice() + "");
                    else {
                        textView.setText(object.getPrice() + "");

                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void drawSubText(TextView textView, Sm object) {
                if (object != null && object.getPrice() != null) {
                    if (LngID == 0)
                        textView.setText(object.getPrice() + "");
                    else {
                        textView.setText(object.getPrice() + "");

                    }
                }
            }


        };

        priceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        amountspiner.setAdapter(priceAdapter);

        amountspiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                slectedSmsEntity = (Sm) priceAdapter.getItem(position);

                Log.e("slectedSmsEntities", slectedSmsEntity.toString());


            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: sort the data before/when giving it to your adapter. adapters just use data to then create multiple views

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for your support :), but how can I do this through adapter class I have posted my adapter class please check :D

Comment: Can you post the code where you're passing the data into the adapter as well? Thanks.

Comment: @TirthMehta please check I have edited my post :)

Comment: well, you don't have to do it in the adapter, you are passing the data here: `new GenericArrayAdapter<Map.Entry>(getContext(), filterSms())` right, so just change the ordering for `filterSms()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a Comparator like this for your `Sm` class before passing it into the adapter. Just like what the first comment said.

```
                Collections.sort(slectedSmsEntities, new Comparator<Sm>(){
                    public int compare(Sm s1, Sm s2) {
                        return s2.getPrice() > s1.getPrice() ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro this answer is solved my issue :), but I'll do a small edit

Comment: No problem, happy to help (: